# Cannot populate drop down menu dynamically in R shiny

Tags: r, csv, shiny

I am trying to create an APP using R Shiny. I want to upload data (.csv file). Then I want to populate the column names in CSV file in a drop down menu. I am unable to do that.

Please refer to the codes below :

---- server.r -----

```
library(shiny)
options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 32*1024^2)


shinyServer(


function(input, output){ 

data <- reactive({
  file1 <- input$file
  if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
  read.table(file=file1$datapath,head=TRUE,sep=",")

})

output$sum <- renderTable({
  if(is.null(data())){return ()}
  summary(data())

})

output$table <- renderTable({
  if(is.null(data())){return ()}
  data()
})

# the following renderUI is used to dynamically generate the tabsets when the file is loaded. Until the file is loaded, app will not show the tabset.
output$tb <- renderUI({
  if(is.null(data()))
    h5("no file loaded")
  else
    tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Data", tableOutput("table")),tabPanel("Summary", tableOutput("sum")))
})

   output$col <- renderUI({

  selectInput("phenomena", "Select the Phenomena",  names(data))
  })

})
```

----- ui.R -----

```
 library(shiny)


 shinyUI(fluidPage(

 titlePanel("Hotspot Analysis of EnviroCar Data"),
 sidebarLayout(
 sidebarPanel(

  # uploading the file 
   fileInput("file","Upload *.csv file"), # fileinput() function is used to get the file upload contorl option

  uiOutput("col")


),

mainPanel(  uiOutput("tb") )

)

))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the problem is in `server.R`:

```
selectInput("phenomena", "Select the Phenomena",  names(data))
```

Here, you're using `data` without parentheses so what you actually obtain is the source code of the function `data`, and `names(data)` is `NULL`. I think all you need is to replace `names(data)` by `names(data())`.