# How to populate csv files of a subdirectory inside shiny app in drop-down menu.?

Tags: r, csv, shiny

**Possible duplicate**

[Cannot populate drop down menu dynamically in R shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28162306/cannot-populate-drop-down-menu-dynamically-in-r-shiny)

I have a small shiny app with some drop-down option for user. I created a subdirectory say `data` inside shiny app containing csv files to appear in the drop-down menu. I used the below code, but i am not able to access the files in the `data` subdirectory.

On ui.r:

```
    filenames <- list.files(pattern="\\.csv") 
   selectInput(inputId="dataset",label= "Choose platform annotation file",filenames)
```

server.r:

```
dataInput <- reactive({
    if (grepl("[/\\\\]", input$dataset)) {
      stop("Invalid dataset")
    }
    read.csv(file.path("data", input$dataset))
  })

  output$annotation <- renderDataTable({
    withProgress(message = 'Loading Data . . .', {
      dataInput()

    })
  })
```

The above code allows me to access the csv files if they are inside the app as my `server.r` and `ui.r` is , not in the separate subdirectory inside shiny app.

I also want to know is this the correct way to access the data of above code, as i am not able to access the data further in my below code.

```
inputdata <- reactive({ 

    df1 <- data.frame()
    df1 <- dataInput()
    if (is.null(df1))
      return(NULL)
    df1[] <- lapply(df1, as.character)
    df1 <- df1[df1[,3]!='',]
    df1 <- df1[!grepl('[/]', df1$Gene.Title),]
  })
```

I tried this also

```
    filenames <- list.files(pattern="\\.csv$data") ## data is my folder inside shiny app.
```

to access the`data` subdirectory inside shiny app with csv files, but not able to do.

Edited: Input file example

```
ID                        Gene Title                      Gene Symbol
1007_s_at   discoidin domain receptor tyrosine kinase 1    DDR1
1053_at     replication factor C (activator 1) 2, 40kDa    7-Mar
117_at      heat shock 70kDa protein 6 (HSP70B')           HSPA6
121_at      paired box 8                                   PAX8
1255_g_at   guanylate cyclase activator 1A (retina)        GUCA1A
1294_at     ubiquitin-like modifier activating enzyme 7    UBA7 
1320_at     protein tyrosine phosphatase, non-receptor     PTPN21
1405_i_at   chemokine (C-C motif) ligand 5                 CCL5/CCL6
1431_at      
1438_at     EPH receptor B3                                EPHB3
1487_at     estrogen-related receptor alpha                ESRRA
1494_f_at   cytochrome P450, family 2                      CYP2A6/CYP2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `list.files`, you need to specify the path you want to list the files of, the default path is the current directory, which would be the directory where you have the `ui.R` and `server.R` file.

Try:

```
filenames <- list.files(path="data",pattern="\\.csv")
```

You can put this line before the `shinyUI(...)` in your `ui.R` file.

For the second part of your code, it looks like you want to clean up the data, you could do (I changed `inputdata` to `clean_data` to make it clearer):

```
clean_data <- reactive({ 
        #get the data 
        df1 <- dataInput()

        if (is.null(df1))
                return(NULL)
        df1[] <- lapply(df1, as.character)

        #looks for lines that have only zero or more blanks or a slash in column 3 and removes them
        df1 <- df1[!grepl("$ *^|/",df1[,3]),]
        df1
}) 

#do what you want with the data, for expample render it as another table
 output$annotation <- renderDataTable({
            withProgress(message = 'Loading Data . . .', {
                  clean_data()

            })
    })
```

Also, looking at your input file examples you have a lot of `Gene title` that have commas, this might cause issues if your the separator in your `csv` file is a comma.

Comment: Thanks, this works. What about other issue in the above question.

Comment: I don't really know what you mean, or what the problem is. Once the data is loaded `dataInput()` does return the dataframe for me. What's the problem? Maybe posting a few lines of your data will also help.

Comment: Here also it return the data frame. Please look at the above code in `inputdata` part, i need the data for further processing, which i am not able to do. I may be missing something i think, i am not sure. Need to look at the code again.

Comment: ok, can you also post a few lines of one of your `csv` file to see what it looks like and if the code that is in `inputdata` runs fine on it?