# How to populate drop down menu in shiny's ui.R using rscript code?

Tags: r, csv, shiny

I have some .csv files in one of my directories and want to read them in ui.R to populate drop down list's choices parameter. But I am unable to do so. I have referred these links but they didn't not seem to help me.
[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28914411/how-to-populate-csv-files-of-a-subdirectory-inside-shiny-app-in-drop-down-menu)
and
[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28914411/how-to-populate-csv-files-of-a-subdirectory-inside-shiny-app-in-drop-down-menu)

Here is my code for ui.R

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
  #this is where I start with my normal rscript code
  #I don't know even if this is allowed but shiny does
  #not give me any error in the source code
  files <- Sys.glob("/home/ubuntu/r-stockPrediction-master/input/*.csv"),
  selection = c(),
  for(i in 1:length(files)){
    selection[i] = strsplit(strsplit(files[i],"/")[[1]][6],".csv")
  },
  selectInput("choice","Select your choice",choices=selection),

  verbatimTextOutput("text")
)
```

Here is my code for server.R

```
library(shiny)


server <- function(input,output){
  output$text <- renderPrint({
    paste("you selected",input$choice,sep=" ")
  })

}
```

When I run my server, the browser page say

```
ERROR: object 'selection' not found
```

I hope I have provided everything relevant. If you need any further information please feel free to ask. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to put the file call in the server.r and leave ui.r to just hold what the app looks like - all data calls and dynamic stuff like what you are asking should be in server.r.  Best to work through some of the examples on shiny.rstudio.com - this article is most relevant http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html

Comment: checked out the link that you have mentioned. But I don't want any dynamic things. I just want to list all of my files and show them in the drop down @MarkeD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution for my problem after thousands of trial and error. What I did is, I wrote a new rscript file that contains a function "listfiles()" to return a vector containing all the names of the files. In the ui.R file I added the source(path) function to locate the new rscript file, where path is the path to the new script file. In the drop down function of selectInput(), I simply make parameter choices = listfiles() and it works like magic. See the code below for good understanding.

This is my listfiles.R script

```
    listfiles <- function(){

    files <- Sys.glob("/home/ubuntu/r-stockPrediction-master/input/*.csv")

    l = list()
    for(i in 1:length(files)){
      l[[i]] = strsplit(strsplit(files[i],"/")[[1]][6],".csv")
    }

    vect = c()
    for(i in 1:length(files)){
      vect[i] = l[[i]][[1]][1]     
    }
    return (vect)
  }
```

This is my ui.R file

```
library(shiny)
source("listfiles.R")

ui <- fluidPage(

  selectInput("choice","Select your choice",choices = listfiles()),

  verbatimTextOutput("text")
)
```

No changes have been made to the server.R file. And this works. I think, now whenever I require some automated task to be included in the shiny scripts, I will just make external rscript files containing the required function that returns the value I want.

Changes after the edit

This is my ui.R file

```
library(shiny)
source("listfiles.R")

ui <- fluidPage(

  uiOutput("stocknames"),

  verbatimTextOutput("text")
)
```

This is my server.R file

```
library(shiny)
source("listfiles.R")

server <- function(input,output){

  stock_names <- reactive({
    return(listfiles())
  })
  output$stocknames <- renderUI({
    selectInput("choices","Select your choice",choices = as.vector(stock_names()))
  })


  output$text <- renderPrint({
    paste("you selected",input$choices,sep=" ")
  })

}
```

Comment: this is an unnecessarily hacky way to accomplish something relatively basic... You don't want to invoke functions with ui.r, the UI should just reference values already calculated in server.r. Try making listfiles a reactive function, then referencing it in a renderUI that should live in server.r, then have the ui.r reference that renderedUI

Comment: @hedgedandlevered Would you please explain why we don't want to invoke functions with ui.r ?

Comment: @hedgedandlevered I have been trying to do the things the way you have suggested but I have a problem. You see that my listfiles() function returns a vector. How to write that function inside reactive() ? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: I'm at work so I cant take any time, but I'll make an answer tonight or tomorrow night